# Im Taking Request_handler_not_found

Tags: java, kotlin, dji-sdk

I am currently experiencing an issue with a "Request Handler Not Found" message while working on a waypoint mission. I am trying to initiate a waypoint mission using the DJI SDK, but I keep receiving this error message.

I have reviewed the documentation thoroughly and ensured that my code aligns with the provided guidelines. However, the error persists. I suspect there might be an issue with the configuration or the setup of the mission.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem before? Could someone please guide me on how to resolve this issue or provide any insights on what might be causing this error? I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.

I have reviewed the documentation thoroughly and ensured that my code aligns with the provided guidelines.

Comment: Share your code